# How do I filter columns in a dataframe by the keys in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My first dataframe is

```
obj1 obj2 obj3
 01   02   03
 02   03   04
```

another dataframe is:

```
col1 col2 col3
obj1  M    N
obj2  M    T
obj3  M    N
```

I only want the columns in the first dataframe who are marked with

```
{'col2':M, 'col3':N}
```

The wanted result is

```
obj1 obj3
 01   03
 02   04
```

I can't seem to achieve this in a decent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is convert dictionary to one row `DataFrame` and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html), because no parameter `on` it merging by intersection of all columns names (in helper DataFrame by keys of dictionary):

```
d = {'col2':'M', 'col3':'N'}

vals = pd.DataFrame([d]).merge(df2)['col1']
```

Or use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with dict comprehension:

```
vals = df2.query(' & '.join(['{}=={}'.format(i,repr(j)) 
                              for i, j in d.items()]))['col1']
```

And then filter by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), `:` means all rows:

```
df = df1.loc[:, df1.columns.isin(vals)]
print (df)
  obj1 obj3
0   01   03
1   02   04
```